# How do I change the "sleep" function to work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, function, internet-explorer, syntax-error

So I have a website where you can click a button which then redirects you to a different page. The redirection should not happpen instantly but after like 3 seconds. For this I found here on Stackoverflow a code snippet which works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but it doesn't in Internet Explorer.

Tested it in Chrome and Firefox where it works perfectly fine.
Doesn't in Internet Explorer though..

```
function sleep(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    async function redirect(user) {
        await sleep(500);
        document.getElementById("redirect" + user).innerHTML = "Redirecting.";
        await sleep(700);
        document.getElementById("redirect" + user).innerHTML = "Redirecting..";
        await sleep(700);
        document.getElementById("redirect" + user).innerHTML = "Redirecting...";
        await sleep(700);
        window.open("url", "_newtab");
        await sleep(1000);
        document.getElementById("redirect" + user).innerHTML = "";
    }
```

Should redirect me to a site after some time.
Doens't work in Internet Explorer.

Error Message: "Syntaxerror"

Where?: `=>` in `return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));`

Comment: Internet Explorer supports no arrow functions.

Comment: Not to mention promises and `async`/`await`.

Comment: Backport your script with Babel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code uses several features IE11 doesn't have:

- Promises
- Arrow functions
- `async`/`await`

Either don't use those, or transpile to ES5 and include a promise polyfill. [Babel](https://babeljs.io) is one tool you can use for that.

In that code, "not using those" would probably be to simply nest the `setTimeout` callbacks:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("redirect" + user).innerHTML = "Redirecting.";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("redirect" + user).innerHTML = "Redirecting..";
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("redirect" + user).innerHTML = "Redirecting...";
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.open("url", "_newtab");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementById("redirect" + user).innerHTML = "";
                }, 1000);
            }, 700);
        }, 700);
    }, 700);
}, 500);
```

Although you could do it with a loop as well.

You can see why the newer features are desirable.

Answer (score 1):

IE11 (released in 2013) does not support `async` functions (specified in ES2017), or arrow functions, or Promises. Use `setTimeout` instead:

```
function makeTimeout(time, user, msg) {
  setTimeout(time, function() {
    document.getElementById("redirect" + user).innerHTML = msg;
  }, time);
}
function redirect(user) {
  makeTimeout(500, user, "Redirecting.");
  makeTimeout(500 + 700, user, "Redirecting..");
  makeTimeout(500 + 700 + 700, user, "Redirecting...");
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.open("url", "_newtab");
  }, 500 + 700 + 700 + 700);
  makeTimeout(500 + 700 + 700 + 700 + 1000, user, '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` directly without a `Promise` to do this.

```js
function redirect(user) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("redirect" + user).innerHTML = "Redirecting.";
    }, 500);
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("redirect" + user).innerHTML = "Redirecting..";
    }, 1200);
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("redirect" + user).innerHTML = "Redirecting...";
    }, 1900);
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.open("url", "_newtab");
    }, 2600);
}
```